# Getting 'Didn't find class "java.util.Base64"' error despite using android.util.Base64

Tags: java, android

As in the question, i've problem with using Base64, constantly gettin the error

```
Failed resolution of: Ljava/util/Base64;

Didn't find class "java.util.Base64" on path:
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.app/lib/x86,
/data/app/com.app/base.apk!/lib/x86,
/system/lib,
/vendor/lib]]
```

There is the import

```
import android.util.Base64;
```

and the only part of code using Base64

```
Log.d("appname", "BUFFER UTF8: " + Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT));

String signature = generator.sign(keyFile, Base64.decode(data, Base64.DEFAULT));
Log.d("appname", "Signature " + signature);
```

Any idea?

upd.

found one of imported 3rd party libraries in my class uses `java.util.Base64`. Idk what should i do next

Answer (score 0):

You are importing Base64 of android, check you rimport statement.
Change your code like this: -

```
Log.d("appname", "BUFFER UTF8: " + Base64.decode(data, Base64.NO_WRAP));
String signature = generator.sign(keyFile, Base64.decode(data, Base64.NO_WRAP));
Log.d("appname", "Signature " + signature);
```

Comment: Yup, but why error all about java.util when i'm using android.util?
Btw same error with `Base64.NO_WRAP`

Comment: Can you show complete class for this? It will give more details to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely, either using `java.util.Base64` in a different class, or you are using some 3rd-party Java library library that uses the class.

So:

1. Search your *entire* source codebase for an import of `java.util.Base64`.  If you find one, fix it.
2. Check the logcat again and see if it tells you what class *depends on* the the incorrect `java.util.Base64` class.
3. If the previous don't help you find the source of the problem, you could try extracting all of the `.class` files from the JARs in your project's dependency tree, running each one through `javap` to decompile the code and `grep` for references to that class.  (There may be a more elegant way to do this ...)

---

> I found that one of imported 3rd party libraries in my class uses `java.util.Base64`. I don't know what should I should do next.

A library that uses `java.util.Base64` is not designed for Android, and certainly won't have been tested on Android.

There are two paths you could take:

- If source code for the library is available, you could try *porting* it to Android.  Replace `java.util.Base64` with `android.util.Base64`, and replace any other classes that are not available on Android.  Build, test, and so on.
- Use Google to see if someone has already done the porting work.
- If source code is not available or if porting the library (and maintaining the port) is too hard, look for an alternative library.